# Getting 404 after deploying Laravel 8 on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to set up an staging environment (I also intend to set up a production futhermore) for a Laravel 8 application. almost everithing is working as I expected, except for a problem caching the routes and with something wrong on nginx configuration.
I created a `laravel.conf` file on `.platfom/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk` folder with the following content:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    gzip_static on;
}
```

but it seem to take no effect.

Here are the configuration files that I'm using:

```
01-setup.config:

commands:
  01updateComposer:
    command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update
option_settings:
  - namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment'
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root
  - namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini'
    option_name: document_root
    value: /public
  - namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini'
    option_name: composer_options
    value: '--no-dev --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader'
container_commands:
  01-install_composer_dependencies:
    command: >-
      sudo php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/bin/composer.phar install --no-dev
      --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
    cwd: /var/app/staging
  02-optimize:
    command: /usr/bin/composer.phar dump-autoload --optimize


03-artisan.config

container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: php artisan migrate --force
    cwd: /var/app/staging/
    leader_only: true
  02_seed:
    command: php artisan db:seed --force
    cwd: /var/app/staging/
    leader_only: true
  03_clear_route:
    command: sudo php artisan route:clear
    cwd: /var/app/staging/
  04_clear_cache:
    command: sudo php artisan cache:clear
    cwd: /var/app/staging/
  05_clear_optimize:
    command: sudo php artisan optimize:clear
    cwd: /var/app/staging/
  06_optimize:
    command: sudo php artisan optimize
    cwd: /var/app/staging/
  07_clear_config:
    command: sudo php artisan config:clear
    cwd: /var/app/staging/
  08_link_storage_folder:
    command: sudo php artisan storage:link
    cwd: /var/app/staging/

04-change-permissions.config

container_commands:
  01_storage_permissions:
    command: chmod 777 -R /var/app/staging/storage
    cwd: /var/app/staging/
  02_cache_permissions:
    command: chmod 777 -R /var/app/staging/bootstrap/cache/
    cwd: /var/app/staging/
```

I also tried to override the default nginx.conf but I didn't succeeded.

Some environmets detalis:

EB platform: PHP 7.4 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2

NGINX: 1.18.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the UI (Configuration -> Software section) you should set the **Document Root** setting to `/public`.

See [AWS tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-laravel-tutorial.html) for more information

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I already did that in a ebextension file.

Comment: If you did that, you don't need custom NGINX config. It should work without it. See the tutorial I linked in my response.

Comment: I kinda need that cause I deployed using EB CLI. I'll edit my question providing more information. I'm following this tutorial: http://blog.goforyt.com/laravel-5-aws-elastic-beanstalk-production-guide/

Comment: So many questions comes to my mind. What PHP version platform do you use? Are you using Amazon Linux 1 or 2? By default if you use PHP platform you have the web server already configured (AL1 with Apache and AL2 with Nginx).

Comment: Those informations was already in my question: I'm using AL2, PHP 7.4 and nginx 1.18.0. I'm recreating the entire environment while we discuss it. I would provide any aditional information to help us to solve this problem that I'm stuck on since last week

Comment: I looked at the tutorial you're using and most likely it's targeted at version 1. If you don't do anything fancy you don't need custom NGinx config. Change the "Document Root" to `/public`, redeploy and it should work.

Comment: Yeah, this tutorial is just a baseline, I had to modify some things like paths and some commands. I'm able to change the document root without problems on the file 01-setup.config (I always check on the UI).

Comment: @NathanLima and you still got 404? Try accessing /public folder of your application and check if it works.

Comment: Yep! It's very strange! I'm recreating the environment to see if it works now, but I tried to access /public folder almost every time that I deployed some change in my old environment... I also tried to put /index.php and /public/index.php but they also didn't work...

Comment: There must be something wrong with the environment itself. 1. Kill the instance and let it rebuild. 2. Try to recreate the environment from the scratch without custom config. Change Document Root to /public and deploy. It should work. 3. Than if it works add custom config. Don't add Nginx config as it's not needed.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try!